# Instagram hook com.instagram.exclusivegram for live app

Tags: ios, instagram

I want to share a photo to instagram. The app (ios7+) is live, on AppStore. For my test devices or simulator, this code works fine.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"]]) {
    _fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instagramPhoto.igo"]];
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: self.imageForInstagram]];
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) writeToURL:_fileURL atomically:YES ];
    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", _fileURL]];
    self.documentInteractionForInstagram = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
    self.documentInteractionForInstagram.delegate = self;
    self.documentInteractionForInstagram.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    self.documentInteractionForInstagram.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"title" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [self.documentInteractionForInstagram presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0) inView:self.viewTosend.view animated:YES];
}
```

For the live app I get :
[image]

and nothing happened (i have instagram app on my live device and i am login).

Did I forgot something? It is different for a live app?

Answer (score 0):

The delegate for documentInteractionForInstagram is not self, is viewTosend. (only in ios8)

```
    self.documentInteractionForInstagram.delegate = (id)self.viewTosend.view;
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Any object can be the delegate as long as it conforms to the delegate protocol.